# Puppet - mco - passing parameters

Tags: parameters, tags, puppet

I have different manifest files in puppet server.  two questions I have.

1. How can I push a specific manifest file to be run on a set of agents using mco command?
2. How can I pass parameters to the manifest file from puppet master commandline (from mco).

Is there a way to use tags to do it? ie, do different set of operations using different tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master picks the manifest for each agent going by the respective `$certname` value. It is used for looking up `node` blocks in your manifest.

However, you are not bound to structure your manifest by `node`. If security is not much of a concern, you could use a custom fact like so

```
# site.pp
case $::task {
  'taskA': { include taskA }
  'taskB': { include taskB }
  ...
}
```

Then pass the desired value using

```
FACTER_task=taskB puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize
```

It should not be difficult to teach `mco` to do something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks Felix, now i am stuck with how to pass the FACTER_ to puppet agent from mco.  Anyway?

Comment: The `FACTER_*` environment variables are just one way for adding facts. It's especially trivial for command line testing. For production and use via `mco`, you may wish to deploy actual [custom facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/custom_facts.html).

Comment: ok, custom facts are for identifying something already there on the machines, but here I am trying to input a new build filename for deploying via mco from puppet master.

Comment: Facts can return whatever the hell you want. Would it be feasible to make one `mco` call to preseed your custom fact with the value you need, and *then* run `puppet` via `mco`?

Comment: Preseeding a fact - That is a very interesting idea(definitely worth considering). Can you tell me how this kind of deployment done in general? reiterating my scenario, the builds will arrive at a folder in master, the ops guy will select a build(filename) and push it to the agents.

Comment: This kind of deployment is not among Puppet's core competences at all, at least in the agent/master configuration. You may have an easier time pushing generated manifests out to your nodes and relying on `puppet apply` instead.

Comment: Thanks Felix, very helpful perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

if we are exporting any variable start with FACTER_ , will be treated as facter on puppet/facter installed machine. Like

export FACTER_test_value='myname'

facter |grep -i test_value

test_value => myname

So, with mco we can use following commandto pass facter value

mco rpc shell start command='export FACTER_test_fact=“true1"; puppet agent -t --tags testmodule' -I target-server-name